# Embedding distance constraints in the plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, reference-request

Let me first state my question somewhat vaguely. I am interested for which sets of "distance constraints" between $n$ points can be realised in the Euclidean plane.

More precisely suppose you're given an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix of real numbers. Let's call the element in $i$-th row and $j$-th column $d_{i,j}$. We have  $d_{i,j}=d_{j,i}$ and $d_{i,i}=0$ for all $i,j$.

What conditions does this matrix need to satisfy for there to be a collection of $n$ points in the plane (let's mark them $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$) such that the Euclidean distance $d(P_i,P_j)= d_{i,j}$ for all $i,j$?

Clearly any such matrix needs to satisfy the triangle inequality ($d_{i,j}+d_{j,k} \geq d_{i,k}$) but this is clearly not sufficient since it also needs to satisfy Ptolomey's inequality and it's possible to construct matrices which satisfy the triangle but fail to satisfy Ptolomey's inequality. I don't know whether satisfying both inequalities is enough.

I would also be interested if there is an algorithm rather than a set of algebraic conditions such a matrix would need to satisfy.

Comment: There is considerable literature on the question of finding the lowest dimension Euclidean space accommodating a given set of pairwise distances.

Comment: Ah very interesting thanks! Could you point out some of this literature? And in particular I'm interested only in when it can be  accommodated in dimension $2$...

Comment: Sorry, I'd have to work as hard to find the literature as you would, by Googling relevant keyphrases.

Comment: There is a large literature about geometric constraint solving in general. See, for example, https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cmh/distribution/PubsCons.html. And, if you can find a better way to do it, fame and fortune will ensue, because it's very important in CAD.

Comment: You could start by searching for "geometric constraint solver"

Answer (score 1):

Look up the [Cayley-Menger determinant,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) but then look at theorem 2.1 in [this paper.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0349.pdf) (Euclidean distance geometry and applications
Leo Liberti∗ Carlile Lavor† Nelson Maculan‡ Antonio Mucherino)